# Sharing endpoint at infinity

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I could not solve this problem. Can you help me please?

Prove that if m and n are hyperbolic lines that share an endpoint at
infinity, then there does not exist a hyperbolic line perpendicular to both
m and n.

Answer (score 1):

If such a line existed, you'd get an ideal triangle with angle sum 180 degrees.

But every hyperbolic triangle has angle sum strictly less than 180 degrees.

Comment: is this enough to prove the statement?